How to remove all CRLF's at position 51 in a file, processing the file in reverse order
I have a large text file that got word-wrapped at 50 characters by the application that outputs it.
The actual original unwrapped Line length varies wildly from 1 character up to 1500+ characters.
I need something that can process the file in reverse order (starting from the bottom) and remove every CRLF that sits at position 51, but leave all of the CRLF's at OTHER positions alone.
(Hence the reverse order. a 1500+ character line has like 56 CRLF's in it at every position 51. The last ones have to be removed first in order to preserve string integrity).
Due to the necessity of reverse order, as far as I can tell, this means sed is out. Regex find and replace in notepad++ doesn't have "backward direction" as a selectable option either.
I'm on windows. The file itself was generated via powershell, but I have python installed, node,  cygwin via Cmder, and honestly would be willing to install just about anything for this, but wsl is currently out of the question due to a corporate policy. So is vbscript for that matter.
I tried various find and replace extended options in n++ but there are no consistent delineators aside from [CR][LF] at pos51.
Example -- with an attempt to preserve formatting:
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."id" IS 'The unique identifier for a things
andstuf association record.';

COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."course_id" IS 'Identifies the course.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."created_at" IS 'Timestamp of when the reco
rd was created.';

COMMENT ON COLUMN is just one small section of thousands of lines of logging. some start with debug, some start with info, some start with SELECT some start with formatted dates, some start with UPSERT, some start with ON CONFLICT...it varies widely and wildly. --all lines do not end with a semicolon. blank lines being maintained would probably be preferable. –
There are no unique strings of formatted text specific to the start of each line. I may have to (and am willing to) accept that all lines that are complete at 50 characters exactly will be incorrectly merged along with all of the lines that are being correctly merged.
The output is coming from a compiled python application and is being captured via start-transcript in powershell. I cannot affect the output within powershell at the time it is being generated. I can, however, affect the transcript file that powershell outputs after the fact.
The only constant I am able to find is that wrapped lines have a CRLF at position 51.

unless you add an example of what you have and what you want as a result to your question is not possible to help you

if a true line is exactly 50 chars (51 with \r added) then how to determine that such line should not be merged with the next line? do all lines start with a unique string or formatted text?

no, no unique strings of formatted text specific to the start of each line. I may have to accept that all lines that are complete at 50 characters exactly will be incorrectly merged along with all of the lines that are being correctly merged.

based on your latest update: do all true/complete lines start with the string COMMENT ON COLUMN and end with a semi-colon (;)? if not then please update the question to show some true/complete lines that have a different start and end; should blank lines be removed or maintained?

possibly you could use -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{50})\r?\n' in powershell to fix this issue but it would help if you add how the expected output should be once fixed

Sadly, no. COMMENT ON COLUMN is just one small section of thousands of lines of logging. some start with debug, some start with info, some start with SELECT some start with formatted dates, some start with UPSERT, some start with ON CONFLICT...it varies widely and wildly.  --all lines do not end with a semicolon.  blank lines being maintained would probably be preferable.

The output is coming from a compiled python application and is being captured via start-transcript in powershell. I cannot affect the output within powershell at the time it is being generated. I can, however, affect the transcript file that powershell outputs after the fact.

please update the question with these additional details; not everyone is going to spend the time reading through comments trying to piece together the entire picture; the current sample would lead many to surmise all rows start with COMMENT ON COLUMN and end with ; ... so adding some variations to the sample input would eliminate this false assumption about starting/ending of lines

How big is the file? (Get-Content path\to\file.txt -Raw) -replace '(?<!;\s*)(?:\r?\n)' might do the trick if the file contents fit in memory

OP has stated there are no common starts/ends for the true lines.  Modifying OP's sample to show some variation:
$ cat file.txt
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."id" IS 'The unique identifier for a things
andstuf association record.';

some other start  "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."course_id" IS 'Identifies the course.'
yet another start|"vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."created_at" IS 'Timestamp of when the reco
rd was created.'

OP has stated lines end with CR/LF (\r\n) so I insured my file ends with CR/LF:
$ unix2dos file.txt
$ file file.txt
file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

One awk idea:
awk -v maxlen=51 '                                    # set awk variable "maxlen"
length() <  maxlen { print line $0; line = "" }       # if length < 51 then print current value of "line" variable plus current line ($0); reset/clear "line" variable
length() == maxlen { sub(/\r$/,""); line = line $0 }  # if length = 51 then strip the CR (\r) character and append to "line" variable
END                { if (line != "") print line }     # at end of file print "line" if not empty
' file.txt > newfile.txt

#### one-liner sans comments:

awk -v maxlen=51 'length()<maxlen {print line $0; line=""} length()==maxlen {sub(/\r$/,""); line=line $0} END {if (line!="") print line}' file.txt > newfile.txt

NOTES:

if the max length will always be 51 then -v maxlen=51 could be removed and all other references to maxlen would then be replaced with 51
if a true/complete line is exactly 50 characters (+ \r) in length this will erroneously merge said line with the next line from the file

This generates:
$ cat newfile.txt
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"."id" IS 'The unique identifier for a thingsandstuf association record.';

some other start  "vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"."course_id" IS 'Identifies the course.'
yet another start|"vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"."created_at" IS 'Timestamp of when the record was created.'


This was very, very helpful and educational. thank you both very much.

Possibly you could use the pattern (?m)(?<=^.{50})\r?\n, PowerShell example:
$text = @'
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."id" IS 'The unique identifier for a things
andstuf association record.';

COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."course_id" IS 'Identifies the course.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associa
tions"."created_at" IS 'Timestamp of when the reco
rd was created.';
'@

$text -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{50})\r?\n'

Results in:
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"."id" IS 'The unique identifier for a thingsandstuf association record.';

COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"."course_id" IS 'Identifies the course.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"."created_at" IS 'Timestamp of when the record was created.';

If this is the output you're expecting then you can use Get-Content -Raw to get the file content as a single multi-line string and then apply this replacement:
$content = Get-Content path\to\thefile.txt -Raw
$content -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{50})\r?\n' | Set-Content path\to\otherfile.txt

See https://regex101.com/r/sO0miY/1 for details.

Note that line endings are different in a script vs the console.

Should the -replace operator provide a SPACE ' ' character as the replacement?

@lit I don't think so because in that case ..."vendor"."things_andstuf_associations"... would be ..."vendor"."things_andstuf_associa tions".... The idea is to replace the new line character after 50 characters with null as I understood the question.

Yes, that is probably right. I was thinking of the case where a word ended at position 50 and a new word starts on the next line?

line would end with space or next line start with space in that case and this pattern would work correctly @lit however it's OP the one that should clarify this and how to handle that case

Due to the necessity of reverse order, as far as I can tell, this means sed is out: there is no need to process your file in reverse order. Simply concatenate all 51-characters lines until you encounter a line with a different length, concatenate it too, remove all \r\n except the last one, and print.
GNU sed is indeed an option:
sed -En 'H;/^.{51}$/{$!b};s/.*//;x;s/\r?\n//g;p' file.txt


Append a newline plus the current line to the hold space.
If the current line is 51 characters long and is not the last line, go to next line.
Else, empty the pattern space, swap it with the hold space, delete the leading \n and all \r\n, and print.

If your sed is not GNU sed you may need to split this in pieces:
sed -En -e 'H;/^.{51}$/{$!b' -e '};s/.*//;x;s/\r?\n//g;p' file.txt

